What is the Reason for "Error updating Objective-C type information" Error when attempting to open an .xib file in visual studio
I have migrated my xamarin.ios application to .net8 for iOS.
Currently we have created a new project and copied all the files from the old project to new one and we have updated all the packages and got the app running.
However, due to some unknown reason sometimes we are not able to open any .xib file from Visual Studio
We get an error:

Error updating Objective-C type information

and once this issue occurs it will persist
